# How to traverse through a double pointer containing an array of strings?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault

```
// Online C compiler to run C program online
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* word(char w[]) {
    char *temp = w;
    return temp;
}

char** tokens() {
    char *one = word("One");
    char *two = word("two");
    char *three = word("three");
    char *four = word("four");
    char *five = word("five");
    char *six = word("six");
    char *seven = word("seven");
    char *eight = word("eight");
    char *nine = word("nine");
    char *ten = word("ten");
    char *eleven = word("ten");
    char *twelve = word("ten");
    char *thirteen = word("ten");
    
    char *words[13];
    
    words[0] = one;
    words[1] = two;
    words[2] = three;
    words[3] = four;
    words[4] = five;
    words[5] = six;
    words[6] = seven;
    words[7] = eight;
    words[8] = nine;
    words[9] = ten;
    words[10] = eleven;
    words[11] = twelve;
    words[12] = thirteen;
    
    char **pp = words;
    return pp;
}

int main() {
    // Write C code here
    char **pp = (char **)malloc(13 * sizeof(char));
    
    pp = tokens();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", *pp);
        *pp++;
    }
    // for (; *pp; *pp++) {
    //     printf("%s\n", *pp);
    // }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I want the code to print every word contained in the tokens() method. However, in the for loop in main(), it only prints: one, two, three, four, null, and then gets a segmentation fault. If I use the for loop that is commented, it only prints: one, two, three, four. I'm new to C, so pointers are still pretty confusing. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: What is the point of the function `word`? It does nothing else than return its argument.

Comment: I’m just testing some stuff I know it’s not necessary.

Comment: Then don't post it.

Comment: @SebastianSrvn: In general, you are supposed to provide a [mre] for your problem, which means all unnecessary stuff should be removed. As far as I'm concerned, you don't have to remove it for this question, but it would be a good to do this for future questions. Otherwise, your question has a higher chance of being downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime) of the array `words` ends as soon as the function `tokens` returns. Therefore, it is not meaningful for the function `tokens` to return a pointer to this object, because that pointer will be pointing to an object that no longer exists. Dereferencing that pointer will cause [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) (i.e. your program may crash).

If you want the function `tokens` to return a pointer to a valid object, you must ensure that the lifetime of `words` does not end, for example by using dynamic memory allocation (i.e. [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc)) or change the lifetime of `words` to static, by using the `static` keyword.

In your case, it would be best to remove the function `tokens` and to simply define the variable `words` inside the function `main`, like this:

```
static const char *const words[] = {
    "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
    "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten",
    "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen"
};
```

If you really want to keep the function `tokens`, then you can rewrite it like this:

```
const char *const * tokens( void )
{
    static const char *const words[] = {
        "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
        "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten",
        "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen"
    };

    return words;
}
```

That way, the function `tokens` will return a pointer to a statically allocated object, which has static (unlimited) lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few errors:

```
char **pp = (char **)malloc(13 * sizeof(char));
```

When allocating memory, you want to allocate `sizeof(<oneLevelUp>) * numOfElements`.  In this case, you're allocating for a `char**`, so "one level up" is a `char*`.  Additionally, [no need to cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).  Change that to

```
 char **pp = malloc(13 * sizeof(char*));
```

Finally, the best-considered practice is to include the variable name when using `sizeof`.  This means there will be less maintenance if variable *type* ever changes:

```
 char **pp = malloc(13 * sizeof(*pp));  // preferred method
```

`*pp` is a `char*` type.  If you change that to

```
 int **pp = malloc(13 * sizeof(*pp));
```

now `*pp` is an `int*` type automatically, without having to change the `sizeof` parameter from `char*` to `int*`.

The other problems have already been addressed in comments and answers.  `word` essentially does nothing, as it simply returns the argument passed into it; this function will surely get optimized out.  @AndreasWenzel's answer explains what's wrong with `tokens`.  The top-rated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) has an amusing anecdote about returning pointers to local variables.

One more final note, even if `tokens` didn't invoke UB, you would be/are creating a memory leak by assigning `pp` to the return value of `tokens`.

```
char **pp = malloc(13 * sizeof(*pp));
if (pp == NULL)
{
  // uh oh, we're out of memory, handle the error however you want. For this example, just exit
  exit(-1);
}

// uh oh, by making this assignment, pp no longer points to the memory block
// returned from `malloc`. Now that memory is reserved and nothing points to
// it. If we did this over and over, our process would continue to consume
// memory until none was left.
pp = tokens();
```